# Header may not contain more than a single header

Tags: php

The following code shows an Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in /home1/autocab/public_html/user/companies/cdetails.php on line 30 while running

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();
if($_SESSION['sid']==session_id())
{
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $cname = $_POST['CompanyName'];
$rdate = $_POST['RegistrationDate'];
$abn = $_POST['abn'];
$acn = $_POST['acn'];
$otype = $_POST['otype'];
$ctype = $_POST['ctype'];
$tinfo = $_POST['Trustinfo'];
$asic = $_POST['asic'];
$staus = $_POST['status'];
$lcont = $_POST['lastcontacted'];
$agent = $_POST['agent'];
$cowner = $_POST['cowner'];
$sqlid = $_POST['sqlid'];
$addr = $_POST['addr'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zip= $_POST['zip'];
$taddrs = $_POST['taddrs'];
$note= $_POST['note'];

 }

header("location:https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Accounts/insertRecords?authtoken=&newFormat=1&scope=crmapi&xmlData=<Accounts><row no=%221%22><FL val=%22Account Name%22>" . $cname . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $rdate . "</FL><FL val=%22ACN Number%22>" . $acn . "</FL><FL val=%22ABN Number%22>" . $abn . "</FL><FL val=%22Organization Type%22>" . $otype . "</FL><FL val=%22Client Type%22>" . $ctype . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $tinfo . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $asic . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $staus . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $lcont . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $agent . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $cowner . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $sqlid . "</FL><FL val=%22Address%22>" . $addr . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $city . "</FL><FL val=%22State%22>" . $state . "</FL><FL val=%22Zip Code%22>" . $zip . "</FL><FL val=%22City%22>" . $taddrs . "</FL><FL val=%22Note%22>" . $note . "</FL></row></Accounts>");
      }
     else
     ?
```

Comment: your `if` condition is closed wrongly and a misplaced `else` found. Edit the code structure and try again

Comment: Because of your xml, it mistook every single space as a new header, they should be `%20`